# Работа с большим объемом данных через бд или файл?

Tags: php, sql, файлы

Вопрос в следующем. Есть файл html с таблицей. Из которой парсятся строки ( с ними выполняются определенные операции), как правильнее будет хранить эту информацию? В базе данных ( каждая строка запись в бд ) или после всех операций сохранить все это в файл. Смущает то , что таблицы могут быть и 20 строк и 4000. Количество таких таблиц может быть больше тысячи( они создаются пользователями). Редактируются в таблице только 2 поля.

[image: Пример таблицы]

Comment: А что дальше будет происходить с этими данными ? Вообще в БД обычно практичнее. но загрузка из файла, при правильной организации (что бы за раз была нужна порция данных занимающая целиком один файл) может быть быстрее

Comment: ну по идее файл просто будет загружаться на страницу и единственное что в нем будет меняться это крайние 2 столбца.

Comment: А мб как вариант динамически изменяемые данные хранить в бд, а статические писать файл, и линковать его к записям? И получится запись навроде `#1 | "Причина 3" | "Три" | "someRandomFilename.txt"`

Answer (score 2):

Как правильно заметил @Mike, все зависит от того, как будут использоваться данные. А еще от того, что из себя эти данные представляют.

Например, если у этих файлов различается структура столбцов и вам не нужно как либо аггрегировать данные из нескольких файлов, то самым простым вариантом видится хранение в виде файлов.

Если структура данных в таблицах одинакова и вам может понадобиться делать выборки данных одновременно из нескольких исходных таблиц, то лучшим вариантом будет БД.

Comment: Выборки не будет, и структура у них одинаковая у всех. Единственное что будет меняться в файле это 2 крайних столбца. Они редактируемые будут. Каждая таблица соответствует одной записи ( теста, работы) пользователя. Ну я тоже больше к реализации через файл склоняюсь.

Comment: @Давид скажу честно, я бы в таком случае все же использовал БД. Если структура данных одинаковая, то сложность реализации хранения будет сопоставима, но решение с БД гораздо более гибкое и, потенциально, производительное. Подумайте вот еще о чем - вам ведь где-то надо хранить привязку этих файлов к пользователям, БД тут напрашивается сама собой. Но в целом конечно, не зная всех нюансов, не берусь утверждать, что эти плюсы для вас критичны.

Comment: У каждого пользователя есть папка с номером его id на сервере :) но я Вас понял. Спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Правильнее будет хранить в БД, вам будет проще делать изменения в редактируемых столбцах.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?